# Bluetooth LIAC discovery on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I want to use a 3rd party Wii U pro controller as an Xbox controller or mapped to my keyboard/mouse. On my old Linux machine, I could connect to the controller with `hcitool inq --iac=liac`. How can I do this on Windows 10?